# How to remove css attributes from Rich Text to convert ruby string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have blocked here from last few hours. the problem is

```
var rich_text = "<h1 class='some', some_other='some'>This is sentense </h1>"
```

i want remove css classes and other attributes from this string. suggest me a better way to do this.

output should be like this

```
 <h1>This is sentense </h1>
```

i have tried with `strip_tags` `sanitize` `sanitize_css` methods. which is not use full to me. because i want to delete all attributes from rich text.
any suggestions would be great appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey you can use [SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) just pass attributes array as blank so it removes all attributes from tag

```
rich_text = "<h1 class='some', some_other='some'>This is sentense </h1>"

helper.sanitize(rich_text,:attributes => [])
```

Comment: `var rich_text = ...` is this ruby code or javascript?

Comment: @user000001 its ruby string

Comment: So what does `var` do in ruby? I tried it on an online interpreter here: https://repl.it/C1hh/1  and it returns ```undefined method `var' for main:Object```

Comment: @user000001 you can remove it i had used it as it is as OP editing

Comment: just remove `var` it is a typo. understanding purpose i put it here.

Comment: Thanks alot. You saved my time. @vishal JAIN

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org) if not using rails

For example:

```
rich_text = "<h1 class='some', some_other='some'>This is sentense </h1>"

html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML rich_text
h1 = html_doc.at_css "h1"

h1.attributes.each { |attr, _| h1.remove_attribute(attr) }
h1.to_html
```